# how to fix unwanted toggle when input is focused inside toggled div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that toggle (show/hide) when button is clicked. Inside the div there is an input field, **somehow when the input field is clicked it also toggle the div**.

Here is my code:

```
$(".button").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".div-to-be-toggled").toggle("fast",function(){ 
        $(".input-field").focus();
        });
});
```

In CSS the div is set to display:none.

any help will be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a click event on the input field that will prevent the click event on it to bubble from it's parent.

```
 $( ".input-field" ).click(function( event ) {
            event.stopPropagation();
 });
```